# trying to disable focusable, not working, android

Tags: java, android, focus

I am connecting to a terminal emulator using a library in android, this connects to a serial device (a switch) and shows me sent/received data. I send data over serial using another library. I send data over the connection via a text box below the terminal or by typing in the terminal itself and hitting enter on the keyboard in both cases.

However I want to disable input into the terminal, so I tried to set focusable to false. I can still type in it though, Any other way to disable typing into the view?

```
<jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
        android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the EmulatorView, I saw this function:

```
@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return true;
}
```

Perhaps you can change that to return false, and see if it fixes your problem.
If that doesn't help, check

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {}
```

See [source code](http://code.google.com/p/vimtouch/source/browse/libraries/emulatorview/src/jackpal/androidterm/emulatorview/EmulatorView.java?spec=svn43e8b77b5f9fd57f4a1e685426f7052f985aca0e&r=43e8b77b5f9fd57f4a1e685426f7052f985aca0e)

Comment: thanks I'll go look for that, what class was it in, did you see that on github?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/vimtouch/source/browse/libraries/emulatorview/src/jackpal/androidterm/emulatorview/EmulatorView.java?spec=svn43e8b77b5f9fd57f4a1e685426f7052f985aca0e&r=43e8b77b5f9fd57f4a1e685426f7052f985aca0e

Comment: I see that the solution was that these were in the library code       setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true); and that must have been overriding my xml. I set them to false, thanks for the help!